# C++ - Is there a workaround to delegating constructors being not the only members in an initialization list

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, language-lawyer, member

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo() {}
  Foo(int i) 
   : Foo(), m_bar(0) {}

private:
  int m_bar;
};
```

Is there a workaround to making such code valid?

Is there a way to have more than one member in the initialization list if we have a delegating constructor, and what is the reason for such a restriction on having the delegating constructor be the only member in the initialization list.

Comment: What should the compiler initialize `m_bar` to? From his perspective both statements are conflicting because a variable can only be initialized exactly once (e.g declare `m_bar` const if you don't see the issue). You can however assign another value to `m_bar` in the body of the ctor. Notice that such an assignment would happen after the initialization of `m_bar`.

Comment: While it would certainly be possible to add precedence rules for such cases to the language, i would speculate that it was deliberately left out because such things increase complexity (from both a languages and a users perspectice) without really adding any significant benefit.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann How could that work with a non inline ctor?

Comment: @curiousguy Good point; when both ctors are implemented in different translation units, things become non-trivial

Answer (score 2):

The rule that you refer to is defined in `[class.base.init]/6`:

> A mem-initializer-list can delegate to another constructor of the
>   constructor’s class using any class-or-decltype that denotes the
>   constructor’s class itself. If a mem-initializer-id designates the
>   constructor’s class, it shall be the only mem-initializer; the
>   constructor is a delegating constructor, and the constructor selected
>   by the mem-initializer is the target constructor. The target
>   constructor is selected by overload resolution. Once the target
>   constructor returns, the body of the delegating constructor is
>   executed. If a constructor delegates to itself directly or indirectly,
>   the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Suppose a moment that the the delegate constructor could be used together with other mem-initializers:

- you could invoke two different delegates.  But there can be only one construction.  So you'd have a conflict of which one to chose.
- with mem-initializers after the delegation, when the delegate would finish its job, the execution of the delegating constructor would be resumed not with the body but in the remaining mem-initializers.
- But mem-initializers are not like assignments where one assignement could overwrite another.  Mem-initializers invoke constructors of members.  And member variables can be constructed only once.  There would then be a conflict of how to initialize the members in the list, and which constructor to discard.
- This is even worse, since both delegating and delegated constructors have to completely construct a class boject, i.e. all its members.

Here an example to clarify the problem with a member that can be initialized only once, and solutions:

```
class Foo
{
  const int m_bar;              // can be initalized only once 
  int m_zoo;                    // must be constructed (default possible) but can be overwritten
public:
  Foo(): m_bar(1), m_zoo(2) {}  // the constant can never be changed
  Foo(int i) 
   : Foo() {m_zoo=i;}           // you can still change in the body already constructed items
  Foo(int i, int j)            // comprehensive init 
    : m_bar(i), m_zoo(j) {}    // (has all that delegating may want(
  Foo(char a) 
    : Foo(a,2) {};             // delegate to the comprehensive ctor
};
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/S8okid)

The delegation rule aims to keep all this simple. It just means that

- there can be only one constructor that constructs the object and its members (either the constructor itself, or a delegate)
- the delegating constructor just decides of the parameters of the delegate, and can add additional behavior in the constructor body
- (and we all know that the body is invoked only once all the base classes and members are constructed)

So the way to make your design valid is to move all the mem-initilizer to the target constructor, and if needed use parameters of this target constructor to specify values for its mem-initializers. Or to overwrite in the body what was already initialized; but this is not always possible.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is since the initializer list in a constructor must initialize every base and member (in declaration order) that has it's own constructor (default constructor if not otherwise specified), that `: Foo()` must have already done so, and calling some members constructor twice would be bad.

I suppose you could argue in the case of primitives that might be left uninitialized that it could be allowed, but then in such cases assigning them within the function body would be equivalent.